# Script: Save image files in different subfolders

Tags: photoshop-script

I am trying to write a script for Photoshop.
It has to turn an existing image file, into 7 different sized (resolution) images.
So far that works. 
And now it saves them with 7 different file-names (I can controll the suffix).

But what I want is that it saves the files all with the same filenames in different (correspondent) folders, (instead of different suffix in the filename).
That last part I cant get to work.
Can anyone help me so that the script will save the files in subfolders, one for every resolution/sized file? (and perhaps even create them if they do not exist).

Edit:
If I add this part in the code, this will create a subfolder for me.
But it will not save any file into it.
Please help :)

```
 //try{
  var f = new Folder( folder+'/50x50' );
  if( !f.exists ) f.create();
  return f; }catch(e){};
```

Thanks a lot.

```
#target photoshop  
// Setup  
doc = app.activeDocument;   

function saveForWeb(f, width, height, fileSuffix) {  
var originalRulerUnits = app.preferences.rulerUnits;  
app.preferences.rulerUnits = Units.PIXELS;  
var basename = doc.name.match(/(.*)\.[^\.]+$/)[1];  
var thePercentage = width / doc.width * 100;  
var theFile = basename + f + fileSuffix + ".jpg";  


// =======================================================  
var idExpr = charIDToTypeID( "Expr" );  
    var desc2 = new ActionDescriptor();  
    var idUsng = charIDToTypeID( "Usng" );  
        var desc3 = new ActionDescriptor();  
        var idOp = charIDToTypeID( "Op  " );  
        var idSWOp = charIDToTypeID( "SWOp" );  
        var idOpSa = charIDToTypeID( "OpSa" );  
        desc3.putEnumerated( idOp, idSWOp, idOpSa );  
        var idDIDr = charIDToTypeID( "DIDr" );  
        desc3.putBoolean( idDIDr, true );  
        var idIn = charIDToTypeID( "In  " );  
        desc3.putPath( idIn, new File( doc.path ) );  
        var idovFN = charIDToTypeID( "ovFN" );  
        desc3.putString( idovFN, theFile );  
        var idFmt = charIDToTypeID( "Fmt " );  
        var idIRFm = charIDToTypeID( "IRFm" );  
        var idPNtwofour = charIDToTypeID( "PN24" );  
        desc3.putEnumerated( idFmt, idIRFm, idPNtwofour );  
        var idIntr = charIDToTypeID( "Intr" );  
        desc3.putBoolean( idIntr, false );  
        var idTrns = charIDToTypeID( "Trns" );  
        desc3.putBoolean( idTrns, true );  
        var idMtt = charIDToTypeID( "Mtt " );  
        desc3.putBoolean( idMtt, false );  
        var idMttR = charIDToTypeID( "MttR" );  
        desc3.putInteger( idMttR, 255 );  
        var idMttG = charIDToTypeID( "MttG" );  
        desc3.putInteger( idMttG, 255 );  
        var idMttB = charIDToTypeID( "MttB" );  
        desc3.putInteger( idMttB, 255 );  
        var idHScl = charIDToTypeID( "HScl" );  
        var idPrc = charIDToTypeID( "#Prc" );  
        desc3.putUnitDouble( idHScl, idPrc, thePercentage );  
        var idVScl = charIDToTypeID( "VScl" );  
        var idPrc = charIDToTypeID( "#Prc" );  
        desc3.putUnitDouble( idVScl, idPrc, thePercentage );  
        var idSHTM = charIDToTypeID( "SHTM" );  
        desc3.putBoolean( idSHTM, false );  
        var idSImg = charIDToTypeID( "SImg" );  
        desc3.putBoolean( idSImg, true );  
        var idSWsl = charIDToTypeID( "SWsl" );  
        var idSTsl = charIDToTypeID( "STsl" );  
        var idSLAl = charIDToTypeID( "SLAl" );  
        desc3.putEnumerated( idSWsl, idSTsl, idSLAl );  
        var idSWch = charIDToTypeID( "SWch" );  
        var idSTch = charIDToTypeID( "STch" );  
        var idCHsR = charIDToTypeID( "CHsR" );  
        desc3.putEnumerated( idSWch, idSTch, idCHsR );  
        var idSWmd = charIDToTypeID( "SWmd" );  
        var idSTmd = charIDToTypeID( "STmd" );  
        var idMDCC = charIDToTypeID( "MDCC" );  
        desc3.putEnumerated( idSWmd, idSTmd, idMDCC );  
        var idohXH = charIDToTypeID( "ohXH" );  
        desc3.putBoolean( idohXH, false );  
        var idohIC = charIDToTypeID( "ohIC" );  
        desc3.putBoolean( idohIC, true );  
        var idohAA = charIDToTypeID( "ohAA" );  
        desc3.putBoolean( idohAA, true );  
        var idohQA = charIDToTypeID( "ohQA" );  
        desc3.putBoolean( idohQA, true );  
        var idohCA = charIDToTypeID( "ohCA" );  
        desc3.putBoolean( idohCA, false );  
        var idohIZ = charIDToTypeID( "ohIZ" );  
        desc3.putBoolean( idohIZ, true );  
        var idohTC = charIDToTypeID( "ohTC" );  
        var idSToc = charIDToTypeID( "SToc" );  
        var idOCzerothree = charIDToTypeID( "OC03" );  
        desc3.putEnumerated( idohTC, idSToc, idOCzerothree );  
        var idohAC = charIDToTypeID( "ohAC" );  
        var idSToc = charIDToTypeID( "SToc" );  
        var idOCzerothree = charIDToTypeID( "OC03" );  
        desc3.putEnumerated( idohAC, idSToc, idOCzerothree );  
        var idohIn = charIDToTypeID( "ohIn" );  
        desc3.putInteger( idohIn, -1 );  
        var idohLE = charIDToTypeID( "ohLE" );  
        var idSTle = charIDToTypeID( "STle" );  
        var idLEzerothree = charIDToTypeID( "LE03" );  
        desc3.putEnumerated( idohLE, idSTle, idLEzerothree );  
        var idohEn = charIDToTypeID( "ohEn" );  
        var idSTen = charIDToTypeID( "STen" );  
        var idENzerozero = charIDToTypeID( "EN00" );  
        desc3.putEnumerated( idohEn, idSTen, idENzerozero );  
        var idolCS = charIDToTypeID( "olCS" );  
        desc3.putBoolean( idolCS, false );  
        var idolEC = charIDToTypeID( "olEC" );  
        var idSTst = charIDToTypeID( "STst" );  
        var idSTzerozero = charIDToTypeID( "ST00" );  
        desc3.putEnumerated( idolEC, idSTst, idSTzerozero );  
        var idolWH = charIDToTypeID( "olWH" );  
        var idSTwh = charIDToTypeID( "STwh" );  
        var idWHzeroone = charIDToTypeID( "WH01" );  
        desc3.putEnumerated( idolWH, idSTwh, idWHzeroone );  
        var idolSV = charIDToTypeID( "olSV" );  
        var idSTsp = charIDToTypeID( "STsp" );  
        var idSPzerofour = charIDToTypeID( "SP04" );  
        desc3.putEnumerated( idolSV, idSTsp, idSPzerofour );  
        var idolSH = charIDToTypeID( "olSH" );  
        var idSTsp = charIDToTypeID( "STsp" );  
        var idSPzerofour = charIDToTypeID( "SP04" );  
        desc3.putEnumerated( idolSH, idSTsp, idSPzerofour );  
        var idolNC = charIDToTypeID( "olNC" );  
            var list1 = new ActionList();  
                var desc4 = new ActionDescriptor();  
                var idncTp = charIDToTypeID( "ncTp" );  
                var idSTnc = charIDToTypeID( "STnc" );  
                var idNCzerozero = charIDToTypeID( "NC00" );  
                desc4.putEnumerated( idncTp, idSTnc, idNCzerozero );  
            var idSCnc = charIDToTypeID( "SCnc" );  
            list1.putObject( idSCnc, desc4 );  
                var desc5 = new ActionDescriptor();  
                var idncTp = charIDToTypeID( "ncTp" );  
                var idSTnc = charIDToTypeID( "STnc" );  
                var idNConenine = charIDToTypeID( "NC19" );  
                desc5.putEnumerated( idncTp, idSTnc, idNConenine );  
            var idSCnc = charIDToTypeID( "SCnc" );  
            list1.putObject( idSCnc, desc5 );  
                var desc6 = new ActionDescriptor();  
                var idncTp = charIDToTypeID( "ncTp" );  
                var idSTnc = charIDToTypeID( "STnc" );  
                var idNCtwoeight = charIDToTypeID( "NC28" );  
                desc6.putEnumerated( idncTp, idSTnc, idNCtwoeight );  
            var idSCnc = charIDToTypeID( "SCnc" );  
            list1.putObject( idSCnc, desc6 );  
                var desc7 = new ActionDescriptor();  
                var idncTp = charIDToTypeID( "ncTp" );  
                var idSTnc = charIDToTypeID( "STnc" );  
                var idNCtwofour = charIDToTypeID( "NC24" );  
                desc7.putEnumerated( idncTp, idSTnc, idNCtwofour );  
            var idSCnc = charIDToTypeID( "SCnc" );  
            list1.putObject( idSCnc, desc7 );  
                var desc8 = new ActionDescriptor();  
                var idncTp = charIDToTypeID( "ncTp" );  
                var idSTnc = charIDToTypeID( "STnc" );  
                var idNCtwofour = charIDToTypeID( "NC24" );  
                desc8.putEnumerated( idncTp, idSTnc, idNCtwofour );  
            var idSCnc = charIDToTypeID( "SCnc" );  
            list1.putObject( idSCnc, desc8 );  
                var desc9 = new ActionDescriptor();  
                var idncTp = charIDToTypeID( "ncTp" );  
                var idSTnc = charIDToTypeID( "STnc" );  
                var idNCtwofour = charIDToTypeID( "NC24" );  
                desc9.putEnumerated( idncTp, idSTnc, idNCtwofour );  
            var idSCnc = charIDToTypeID( "SCnc" );  
            list1.putObject( idSCnc, desc9 );  
        desc3.putList( idolNC, list1 );  
        var idobIA = charIDToTypeID( "obIA" );  
        desc3.putBoolean( idobIA, false );  
        var idobIP = charIDToTypeID( "obIP" );  
        desc3.putString( idobIP, "\"\"\"\"" );  
        var idobCS = charIDToTypeID( "obCS" );  
        var idSTcs = charIDToTypeID( "STcs" );  
        var idCSzeroone = charIDToTypeID( "CS01" );  
        desc3.putEnumerated( idobCS, idSTcs, idCSzeroone );  
        var idovNC = charIDToTypeID( "ovNC" );  
            var list2 = new ActionList();  
                var desc10 = new ActionDescriptor();  
                var idncTp = charIDToTypeID( "ncTp" );  
                var idSTnc = charIDToTypeID( "STnc" );  
                var idNCzeroone = charIDToTypeID( "NC01" );  
                desc10.putEnumerated( idncTp, idSTnc, idNCzeroone );  
            var idSCnc = charIDToTypeID( "SCnc" );  
            list2.putObject( idSCnc, desc10 );  
                var desc11 = new ActionDescriptor();  
                var idncTp = charIDToTypeID( "ncTp" );  
                var idSTnc = charIDToTypeID( "STnc" );  
                var idNCtwozero = charIDToTypeID( "NC20" );  
                desc11.putEnumerated( idncTp, idSTnc, idNCtwozero );  
            var idSCnc = charIDToTypeID( "SCnc" );  
            list2.putObject( idSCnc, desc11 );  
                var desc12 = new ActionDescriptor();  
                var idncTp = charIDToTypeID( "ncTp" );  
                var idSTnc = charIDToTypeID( "STnc" );  
                var idNCzerotwo = charIDToTypeID( "NC02" );  
                desc12.putEnumerated( idncTp, idSTnc, idNCzerotwo );  
            var idSCnc = charIDToTypeID( "SCnc" );  
            list2.putObject( idSCnc, desc12 );  
                var desc13 = new ActionDescriptor();  
                var idncTp = charIDToTypeID( "ncTp" );  
                var idSTnc = charIDToTypeID( "STnc" );  
                var idNConenine = charIDToTypeID( "NC19" );  
                desc13.putEnumerated( idncTp, idSTnc, idNConenine );  
            var idSCnc = charIDToTypeID( "SCnc" );  
            list2.putObject( idSCnc, desc13 );  
                var desc14 = new ActionDescriptor();  
                var idncTp = charIDToTypeID( "ncTp" );  
                var idSTnc = charIDToTypeID( "STnc" );  
                var idNCzerosix = charIDToTypeID( "NC06" );  
                desc14.putEnumerated( idncTp, idSTnc, idNCzerosix );  
            var idSCnc = charIDToTypeID( "SCnc" );  
            list2.putObject( idSCnc, desc14 );  
                var desc15 = new ActionDescriptor();  
                var idncTp = charIDToTypeID( "ncTp" );  
                var idSTnc = charIDToTypeID( "STnc" );  
                var idNCtwofour = charIDToTypeID( "NC24" );  
                desc15.putEnumerated( idncTp, idSTnc, idNCtwofour );  
            var idSCnc = charIDToTypeID( "SCnc" );  
            list2.putObject( idSCnc, desc15 );  
                var desc16 = new ActionDescriptor();  
                var idncTp = charIDToTypeID( "ncTp" );  
                var idSTnc = charIDToTypeID( "STnc" );  
                var idNCtwofour = charIDToTypeID( "NC24" );  
                desc16.putEnumerated( idncTp, idSTnc, idNCtwofour );  
            var idSCnc = charIDToTypeID( "SCnc" );  
            list2.putObject( idSCnc, desc16 );  
                var desc17 = new ActionDescriptor();  
                var idncTp = charIDToTypeID( "ncTp" );  
                var idSTnc = charIDToTypeID( "STnc" );  
                var idNCtwofour = charIDToTypeID( "NC24" );  
                desc17.putEnumerated( idncTp, idSTnc, idNCtwofour );  
            var idSCnc = charIDToTypeID( "SCnc" );  
            list2.putObject( idSCnc, desc17 );  
                var desc18 = new ActionDescriptor();  
                var idncTp = charIDToTypeID( "ncTp" );  
                var idSTnc = charIDToTypeID( "STnc" );  
                var idNCtwotwo = charIDToTypeID( "NC22" );  
                desc18.putEnumerated( idncTp, idSTnc, idNCtwotwo );  
            var idSCnc = charIDToTypeID( "SCnc" );  
            list2.putObject( idSCnc, desc18 );  
        desc3.putList( idovNC, list2 );  
        var idovCM = charIDToTypeID( "ovCM" );  
        desc3.putBoolean( idovCM, false );  
        var idovCW = charIDToTypeID( "ovCW" );  
        desc3.putBoolean( idovCW, false );  
        var idovCU = charIDToTypeID( "ovCU" );  
        desc3.putBoolean( idovCU, true );  
        var idovSF = charIDToTypeID( "ovSF" );  
        desc3.putBoolean( idovSF, true );  
        var idovCB = charIDToTypeID( "ovCB" );  
        desc3.putBoolean( idovCB, true );  
        var idovSN = charIDToTypeID( "ovSN" );  
        desc3.putString( idovSN, """images""" );  
    var idSaveForWeb = stringIDToTypeID( "SaveForWeb" );  
    desc2.putObject( idUsng, idSaveForWeb, desc3 );  
executeAction( idExpr, desc2, DialogModes.NO );  
// =======================================================  
app.preferences.rulerUnits = originalRulerUnits;  
};  


saveForWeb(960, 960, "_380x380") 
saveForWeb(380, 380, "_380x380")  
saveForWeb(300, 300, "_300x300")  
saveForWeb(210, 210, "_210x210")  
saveForWeb(150, 150, "_150x150")  
saveForWeb(100, 100, "_100x100")  
saveForWeb(50, 50, "_50x50")
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what all your complicated script is trying to achieve, but it is pretty simple to save a file for web like this:

```
    // Set up our web export options    
    var options = new ExportOptionsSaveForWeb();
    options.quality = 100;
    options.format = SaveDocumentType.JPEG;
    options.includeprofile=true;
    activeDocument.exportDocument(tmpFile,ExportType.SAVEFORWEB,options);
```

Or, if you want multiple resolutions, put the above in a loop. There is an example [here](https://gist.github.com/aral/1008359).

Comment: What my script is doing:
It saves an image in 7 different resolutions.
I need this for a webshop.
The filename for the 7 files need to be identical though (Original filename). 
So they need to be placed in 7 different subfolders.
That last part I cant get to work, how do I get the 7 files in 7 different subfolders?

Comment: I still don't see what all the tens of lines of script is for! It takes 5 lines to save a document for web, and just a few more to put it into a loop for different sizes.

Comment: Ok, I get that. I am trying to use the script your link sends me.
That one gives me all kinds of errors though. Not working.

All I need is a script that gives me thouse resolutions and saves them in separate subfolders.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it totally different now.
Got it exactly as I want.

```
// List of sizes:
// 2362x2362x300DPI
// 960x960x72DPI 
// 380x380x72DPI
// 300x300x72DPI
// 210x210x72DPI
// 150x150x72DPI
// 100x100x72DPI
// 50x50x72DPI

#target photoshop
main();
function main(){
if(!documents.length) return;
var startRulerUnits = app.preferences.rulerUnits;
app.preferences.rulerUnits = Units.PIXELS;
var doc = app.activeDocument;
var Name = doc.name.replace(/\.[^\.]+$/, '');
var Path = decodeURI(doc.path);
createNamedSnapshot("Snap 1");
doc.resizeImage(960, undefined, 72, ResampleMethod.BICUBIC);
var outFolder = Folder(Path +"/960x960");
if(!outFolder.exists) outFolder.create();
var saveFile = File(outFolder +"/"+Name+".jpg");
SaveJPEG(saveFile,8);
revertNamedSnapshot("Snap 1");
doc.resizeImage(380, undefined, 72, ResampleMethod.BICUBIC);
outFolder = Folder(Path +"/380x380");
if(!outFolder.exists) outFolder.create();
var saveFile = File(outFolder +"/"+Name+".jpg");
SaveJPEG(saveFile,8);
revertNamedSnapshot("Snap 1");
doc.resizeImage(300, undefined, 72, ResampleMethod.BICUBIC);
outFolder = Folder(Path +"/300x300");
if(!outFolder.exists) outFolder.create();
var saveFile = File(outFolder +"/"+Name+".jpg");
SaveJPEG(saveFile,8);
revertNamedSnapshot("Snap 1");
doc.resizeImage(210, undefined, 72, ResampleMethod.BICUBIC);
outFolder = Folder(Path +"/210x210");
if(!outFolder.exists) outFolder.create();
var saveFile = File(outFolder +"/"+Name+".jpg");
SaveJPEG(saveFile,8);
revertNamedSnapshot("Snap 1");
doc.resizeImage(150, undefined, 72, ResampleMethod.BICUBIC);
outFolder = Folder(Path +"/150x150");
if(!outFolder.exists) outFolder.create();
var saveFile = File(outFolder +"/"+Name+".jpg");
SaveJPEG(saveFile,8);
revertNamedSnapshot("Snap 1");
doc.resizeImage(100, undefined, 72, ResampleMethod.BICUBIC);
outFolder = Folder(Path +"/100x100");
if(!outFolder.exists) outFolder.create();
var saveFile = File(outFolder +"/"+Name+".jpg");
SaveJPEG(saveFile,8);
revertNamedSnapshot("Snap 1");
doc.resizeImage(50, undefined, 72, ResampleMethod.BICUBIC);
outFolder = Folder(Path +"/50x50");
if(!outFolder.exists) outFolder.create();
var saveFile = File(outFolder +"/"+Name+".jpg");
SaveJPEG(saveFile,8);
revertNamedSnapshot("Snap 1");
doc.resizeImage(2362, undefined, 300, ResampleMethod.BICUBIC);
outFolder = Folder(Path +"/2362x2362");
if(!outFolder.exists) outFolder.create();
var saveFile = File(outFolder +"/"+Name+".jpg");
SaveJPEG(saveFile,12);
app.activeDocument.close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES);
app.preferences.rulerUnits = startRulerUnits;
}

function SaveJPEG(saveFile, jpegQuality){
jpgSaveOptions = new JPEGSaveOptions();
jpgSaveOptions.embedColorProfile = true;
jpgSaveOptions.formatOptions = FormatOptions.STANDARDBASELINE;
jpgSaveOptions.matte = MatteType.NONE;
jpgSaveOptions.quality = jpegQuality; //1-12
activeDocument.saveAs(saveFile, jpgSaveOptions, true,Extension.LOWERCASE);
}

function createNamedSnapshot(name) {
    var desc = new ActionDescriptor();
        var ref = new ActionReference();
        ref.putClass( charIDToTypeID('SnpS') );
    desc.putReference( charIDToTypeID('null'), ref );
        var ref1 = new ActionReference();
        ref1.putProperty( charIDToTypeID('HstS'), charIDToTypeID('CrnH') );
    desc.putReference( charIDToTypeID('From'), ref1 );
    desc.putString( charIDToTypeID('Nm  '), name );
    desc.putEnumerated( charIDToTypeID('Usng'), charIDToTypeID('HstS'), charIDToTypeID('FllD') );
    executeAction( charIDToTypeID('Mk  '), desc, DialogModes.NO );
}

function revertNamedSnapshot(name) {
    var desc = new ActionDescriptor();
        var ref = new ActionReference();
        ref.putName( charIDToTypeID('SnpS'), name );
    desc.putReference( charIDToTypeID('null'), ref );
    executeAction( charIDToTypeID('slct'), desc, DialogModes.NO );
}
```